# Add/Remove pick-list values dynamically from within apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to dynamically add/remove pick-list values from within apex?

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating picklist values requires you to use the Metadata API which is not natively supported in Apex. That being said, it is absolutely possible from Apex as long as you are in an execution context where you can make callouts. There is a great wrapper for the API on Github at https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi.